# Detecting Day Change in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

So I've been doing a bit of research on how to tell if it's a new day in my iOS app. Basically, I want to reset a bunch of values to 0 as soon as a new day starts. I've seen that I can use "UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification" which sends a notification at midnight. However, will this still fire if the user killed the app at 9:00AM and opens it up again at 9:00AM the next day?

I also saw that I could use "NSCalendarDayChangedNotification" which to my understanding has the same behavior. My only concern is that if either of these will accomplish detecting a day change even after the user kills the app.

Ideally I'd like to put add the notification observer at the top of my .m file in the viewDidLoad like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resetValues) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and then somewhere else in the file...

```
- (void)resetValues {

... // reset values to 0

}
```

The goal would be for this notification to trigger at the beginning of every day change. Would the code above achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` is only useful while your app is running. But note that it can be called for reasons other than the date changing at midnight.

Comment: I see, so my best bet would to just create a stored value of the current date, and continue to check/overwrite it?

Comment: Yes. You need to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution which saves an integer value (the day) in `NSUserDefaults`

- In AppDelegate create a method `checkDayChange` which compares the `day` component of the current date with a saved value in `NSUserDefaults` (default is 0). If the values are not equal, call `resetValues` and save the current day.

  ```
  - (void)checkDayChange
  {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSInteger currentDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
     NSInteger savedDay = [defaults integerForKey:@"day"]; // default is 0
     if (currentDay != savedDay) {
         [self resetValues];
         [defaults setInteger:currentDay forKey:@"day"];
     }
  }
  ```
- Observe `NSCalendarDayChangedNotification` with selector `checkDayChange`
- Call `checkDayChange` also in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: Ah, so with this all I have to do is observe NSCalendarDayChangedNotification in my AppDelegate.m, and then the checkDayChange method will handle overwriting the current day and resetting the values. Won't the notification be rendered useless if the user kills the app?

Comment: The notification is only useful if the application is active, otherwise the check is performed always when the application was launched or becomes active.

Comment: So even if the user kills the app at a certain time of the day, the check will be performed the next day and update the saved day along with calling the reset method

Comment: @FaisalSyed Yes, exactly.

Comment: Warning: NSCalendarDayChangedNotification is called in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

System observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:NSCalendarDayChangedNotification object:nil];
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendardaychangednotification?language=objc